# Doubly Linked List with some Operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, code-analysis, doubly-linked-list

For Doubly linked list `Q` that has number elements, and we have a pointer to first and last elements we have define two operations.

```
Delete (k): delete k first elements from Q.

Append (c), check the last element from `Q`, if this value  bigger than c, delete this elements and repeat it again until the last element is lower or equal to `c` (or empty `Q`), then insert c as last elements of Q`.`
```

if we repeat sequences of these two operations in arbitrary order for `n` times on empty list `Q`, sum of all cost of theses operation is close to `2n`. why my instructor reach to `2n`? any hint or idea is appreciated.

Comment: You can not generally count costs of any operations with explicit constant unless you specify prices of all individual operations. So basically `2n` is meaningless. Plus, the operation `Delete(k)` runs `O(k)` time, so it's not easy to estimate the overall cost. You need to perform an amortized cost evaluation and/or use some specific operations distribution.

Comment: Dear @Aneri, i think he use from amortize cost and say related to 2n. would you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we "*repeat `Delete` and `Append` in arbitrary order for `n` times on empty list Q*", `Append` is called `n` times; hence exactly `n` list element insertions are performed.

Since the list is initially empty, it never contains more than `n` elements; hence at most `n` list element deletions are performed in the combination of `Delete` and `Append`.

Hence the total number of loops in each of `Delete` and `Append` (including reads in `Append`) is no more than 2`n`.

So all in all, no section of the program is executed more than 2`n` times (counting separately code that may be common to list element insertion, list element deletion, and list element access).

The cost is minimal when `k` is always 0, and `c` non-decreasing (including always 0): we have `n` list element insertions, `n` list element read (one returning empty), `n` emptyness tests, `n-1` element comparisons, and no deletion. The cost thus varies significantly with parameters.

<strike>Note: "*Sum of all cost of theses operation is close to 2`n`*" is ill-defined, thus not even wrong. Worse, if list element deletion, by some bad luck (e.g. code cache miss, debug code..) was much slower than the rest, it could be that the code duration vary by a large factor (much higher than 2) depending on parameters. Hence execution time is NOT **ALWAYS** "*about 2`n`*" for any lousing meaning of that.</strike>

Update: In [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347177/doubly-linked-list-with-some-operations#comment41356966_26347608), we are told that list element insertion and deletion has the same cost 1. There are `n` list element insertions, and between 0 to `n` list element deletions. Hence if we neglect the other costs (which is reasonable is memory allocation cost dominates), the total cost is about `n` to about 2`n` depending on parameters. Further, for many parameters (including `k`>=1 most of the time), there are nearly `n` list element deletions, hence cost is about 2`n` if one insists on a best guess, such as in a multiple choice question with (a) `n`+`k` (b) `n` (c) 2`n` (d) 3`n` as the only options.

Comment: if each elements take 2 cost, one for insert and one for deletion, all cost is 2*n.

Comment: @Mio Mio: no, at least because because it is possible that there is  no deletion at all, e.g. when `k` and `c`are 0, as explained in the butlast paragraph of the answer. Also, the statement does not say that insert and delete have the same cost.

Comment: this is a multiple choice question a) n+k  b) n  c)2n  d) 3n  and our instructor solved as (c).

Comment: @Mio Mio: assuming that insert and delete have the same cost 1: if asked an upper bound, or given `k`>=1, or some other reasonable things, then 2`n` is fine. Otherwise between `n` and `2n` is the best we can say.

Comment: yes insert and delete has the same cost 1. would you please edit your answer with this tips. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> if we repeat these operations in arbitrary order for n times on empty
>   list Q sum of all cost of theses operation is close to 2n

It will actually be `O(n)` since we know the list `Q` is empty.

```
DoStuff(list Q, int n):
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Q.Delete(k) //O(k)
        Q.Append(c) //O(sizeof(Q))
        //or
        //Q.Append(c) //O(sizeof(Q))
        //Q.Delete(k) //O(k)
```

Where `n` is the number of iterations.

Now say the lists aren't empty, then we would have `O(n*(sizeof(Q)+k))`. Explanation for that is below:

Say worse case scenario for `Delete (k)` would be to delete k first elements from `Q` where `k` is the size of `Q`, then we would delete n elements. However, it is more accurate to say `O(k)` because you will always delete the first `k` elements only.

Say worse case scenario for `Append (c)` would be all elements inside of `Q` is greater than the value `c`. This would start from the tail node and delete all nodes from `Q`.
In either order

```
Delete(k) //O(k)
Append(c) //O(sizeof(Q))
```

Or

```
Append(c) //O(sizeof(Q))
Delete(k) //O(k)
```

It would be at worse case for just these two commands is `O(sizeof(Q)+k)`.  Now we know we have to do this `n` iterations, so we finally get `O(n*(sizeof(Q)+k))`

As for what your professor said, the only reason why I could ***imagine*** your professor said `2n` is because there are `2` functions being called `n` times. Therefore `2n`.

Comment: The operations are repeated.

Comment: @MioMio From what I understand, it cannot be *worse case* `2n` especially since we have an empty list `Q`. If the list is not empty, `n`, `Q` length or `sizeof(Q)`, and `k` will be all different independent values.  Therefore I reached worse case to be `O(n*(sizeof(Q)+k))`

Comment: @MioMio The only reason why I could ***imagine*** your professor said `2n` is because there are `2` functions being called `n` times.  Therefore `2n`.